# How to block an event from Primefaces Component in JSF Ajax

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, timeline

In Primefaces Timeline after double click on component event "add" is fired, which creates new node in chart. In my application, I want to disallow user from invoking such action. How is this possible?

Comment: did you use `<p:blockUI block=" :yourFormId" widgetVar="tbd" blocked="#{ManagedBean.YourCondition}" />`

Comment: Did my answer help in any way? If not what was wrong and how can i improve? Please leave a comment, accept or vote.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tricks for that, like

If your call is ajax you can show a loader until it complete ajax request while disabling the screen using `AjaxStatus` [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)

You can also `BlockUI` component, it will block/disable only specific component list in your page using `blockUi` [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml)

You also disable button on clicking and ajax enable on ajax success event.

Comment: BlockUI will block whole component from interacting with user. I want to block only particular event, user has to be able to drag and drop timeline nodes, but must be prevent from adding a new one which is made by double click.

Comment: So you can disable that specific button use `<p:blockUI block="addNewButton" trigger="triggerButton" />`

Comment: This is not a particular button, event is firing when user double clicks wherever on Timeline @Sarz

Comment: post any code sample or running snippet of your problematic code

Answer (score 0):

From my experience `<p:timeline />` is not very flexible yet. As stated in [PrimeFaces Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf) for *editable* attribute:

> If true, the events can be edited, changed, created and deleted. Events can only be editable when the option selectable is true (default). When editable is true, the timeline can fire AJAX events "change", "edit", "add", "delete", "drop". This global setting "editable" can be overwritten for individual events by setting a value in field "editable".

One possible solution to disable (at least) addition of events to timeline but keep editable events, is to prohibit editing globally, but permit editing on an event basis with something like this:

```xml
<p:timeline
    value="#{timelineView.model}"
    selectable="true"
    editable="false"
/>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TimelineView implements Serializable {

    private TimelineModel model;

    public TimelineModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(TimelineModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void initialize() {

        model = new TimelineModel();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2016, Calendar.AUGUST, 3, 0, 0, 0);

        TimelineEvent timelineEvent = new TimelineEvent("Editable Event", cal.getTime());
        timelineEvent.setEditable(true);

        model.add(timelineEvent);
    }
}
```